# Move some JSON data into unique Divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a blogger.com blog and I've managed to create a script that gets the data from the blog - im not very good at js / json so I going at this a little blind ;-)

Id like the output to be in 2 DIVS that are unique with the post ID and content:

This is the script:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test</title>
  </head>
  <body>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function posts(json) {
      // Get five recent posts
      for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++)
      {
        var posturl;  
        // Get rel=alternate for truly post url
        for (var j=0; j < json.feed.entry[i].link.length; j++)
        {
          if (json.feed.entry[i].link[j].rel == 'alternate')
          {
            posturl = json.feed.entry[i].link[j].href;
            break;
          }
        }
        // if the Blogger-feed is set to FULL, then the content is in the content-field
        // if the Blogger-feed is set to SHORT, then the content is in the summary-field
        if ("content" in json.feed.entry[i]) {
          var postcontent = json.feed.entry[i].content.$t;}
        else
        if ("summary" in json.feed.entry[i]) {
          var postcontent = json.feed.entry[i].summary.$t;}
        else var postcontent = "";
        // strip off all html-tags
        var re = /<\S[^>]*>/g; 
        postcontent = postcontent.replace(re, "");
        // reduce postcontent to 200 characters
        if (postcontent.length > 200) postcontent = postcontent.substring(0,200);
        // Get posts title
        document.write("Post Id = "+json.feed.entry[i].id.$t);
        document.write('<br/>');
        document.write("Post content = "+postcontent);
        document.write('<br/><br/>');
      }
        }    
</script>

<script src="http://ironheartuk123.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default?alt=json-in-script&callback=posts"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

When I load the page into a browser I get this on screen:

```
Post Id = tag:blogger.com,1999:blog-5655651846573938667.post-5882120439717312684
Post content = Test post 2

Post Id = tag:blogger.com,1999:blog-5655651846573938667.post-8794205203420774123
Post content = Test post 1
```

And this is what I'd prefer the output to be!

```
<div id="5882120439717312684">Test post 2</div>

<div id="8794205203420774123">Test post 1</div>
```

Once I have that step done I'll be able to move the Divs into the correct position on the page. I think that's the easy bit ;-)

Any help greatly appreciated!!

Comment: It is not a good idea to have the IDs begin with numerals.

Comment: True - im happy to call them id="post-5882120439717312684" etc...

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery:

```
var re = /post-\d+/;
var postId = re.exec(json.feed.entry[i].id.$t);
$("#" + postId[0]).html(postcontent);
```

Comment: Thanks Michal but not sure how to implement that?

Comment: I edited my answer and showed how to extract postId (please keep in mind that you should add error handling).

Comment: Thanks - thats been helpful ;-)